# Hyperlink to fetched data base field

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I am using Dream Weaver

I have coded something like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result ))
   {
      echo"<tr><td><b>";
      echo $row ['hos_name'];
      echo"</tr></td></b>";
    }
```

Can I give a hyperlink to 'hos_name'?

Answer (score 1):

```
  echo"<tr><td><b>";
  echo "<a href="somelink.php">    <--- start a link
  echo $row ['hos_name'];
  echo "</a>"                      <--- close the link
  echo"</tr></td></b>";
```

Comment: </tr> </td> tags are flipped?

Answer (score 0):

It is still not entirely correct formatted
for the rest I think it is allright

```
  echo"<tr><td><b>";
  echo "<a href="somelink.php">    <--- start a link
  echo $row ['hos_name'];
  echo "</a>"                      <--- close the link
  echo"</b></tr></td>";
```

only the location of < /b> has changed

Answer (score 0):

Completer than Ronald and MarcB's code:

```
echo"<tr><td><b>";
echo '<a href="' . $row ['hos_name'] . '">';    <--- start a link
echo $row ['hos_name'];
echo "</a>"                      <--- close the link
echo"</b></tr></td>";
```

Comment: </tr> </td> tags are flipped?

Answer (score 0):

the correct way would be something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result ))
{
    echo"<tr>\r";
    echo"<td>\r";
    echo "<a href=\"".$row['hos_link']."\"><b>".$row ['hos_name']."</b></a>\r";
    echo "</td>\r";
    echo "</tr>\r";
}
```

Comment: Now with **urlencode** being present you think **index.php?=** is still necessary?

Comment: lol i keep editing it to avoid getting down voted buy critics of doom.. :/ but unless you have the link stored and hos_link is it a external link or a internal link to index.php ect whoo knows the correct answer